# How to add a node at cursor position to GraphStream graph on click?

Tags: java, swing, graph, click, graphstream

I am developing a Java Swing application to display a graph using [GraphStream](http://graphstream-project.org/).
When clicking on the graph component (a `ViewPanel`) a node should appear where the click has happened.

This basically works but **adding nodes close to the edges of the `ViewPanel` creates the visual effect of zooming out of the graph**.
Also one of the first few clicks somehow changes the camera's center and/or zoom.

I followed the section "*Working in the GUI thread*" of library's [documentation](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation/).
Thus I am not using a `ViewerListener`.

To make sure the layout is not automatic I use:

```
viewer.disableAutoLayout();
view.getCamera().setAutoFitView(false);
view.getCamera().setViewCenter(0, 0, 0);
view.getCamera().setViewPercent(1);
```

Mouse events are handled like so:

```
view.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        Point3 gu = view.getCamera().transformPxToGu(e.getX(), e.getY());
        Node node = graph.addNode(e.getWhen());
        node.setAttribute("xyz", gu.x, gu.y, 0);
        // System.out.println("camera: " + view.getCamera());
    }
});
```

Printing the camera object showed that there was a padding of `30px`.
I thought the padding causes the problem (it seemed reasonable that enforcing the padding could shrink the graph if something is added in the padding area).
By creating a subclass of the `DefaultCamera` class I could get rid of the padding - but that didn't change anything.

Any ideas why new nodes can't be created at the edges?

Thanks in advance!